# Angularjs sync two horizontal lists

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have two horizontal list that needs to move at the same time, I'm using angularjs.
I managed to get it workingt Jquery Mousewheel (github /brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel).
But since I need the scrollbar to be styled and since firefox don't support that I had to use a JS scrollbar so I tried [Perfect ScrollBar](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar) with a directive  (github angular-perfect-scrollbar) but it didn't seem to show.
This is the code

```
    <div id="content">  
<perfect-scrollbar class="scroller" wheel-propagation="true" minScrollbarLength="100" suppressScrollY="true" wheel-speed="50" useBothWheelAxes="true" refresh-on-change="items">
<ul id = "top" class="horizontal-slide header-slide" >
        <li class="span2 animate-repeat borderlist description" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search"  ng-mouseenter="mouseEnterItem(item)" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeaveItem(item)">

            <a href="#" class="text-block" >
                <div class="vertical-text " ng-class="{textblur: !item.itemMouseOver && itemMouseOver, textShine : item.itemMouseOver && itemMouseOver}">{{item.name}}</div>
            </a>

        </li>

</ul>
</perfect-scrollbar>
  <perfect-scrollbar class="scroller" wheel-propagation="true" minScrollbarLength="100" suppressScrollY="true" wheel-speed="50" useBothWheelAxes="true" refresh-on-change="items">     
<ul id="bottom" class="horizontal-slide ">
    <li class="span2 animate-repeat  borderlist image-block " ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" ng-mouseenter="mouseEnterItem(item)" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeaveItem(item)">
        <ul class="  ">
        <li class="image-li " ng-repeat="img in item.imgs " > 
                    <a href="#" class="">
                  <img src="{{img.img}}" alt=""  ng-class="{imgblur: !item.itemMouseOver && itemMouseOver}" />
                </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</perfect-scrollbar>
</div>
```

If I increase the size of the container I see the vertical JS bar but the horizontal one have a width of 0.

Thanks in advance.

--EDIT--

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SOTRqU9Rzztj7kejM2wn?p=preview)

Comment: I updated my question with a plunker, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar). Look at [example](http://jsfiddle.net/J3ZXU/). If you want to scroll containers with mousescroll, you can apply mousewheel JS handler from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AZ6CZ/) to each container within `onInit` callback.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="top" class="horizontal-slide header-slide scroller scrollbar-outer" jquery-scrollbar="jQueryTopScrollbarOptions">
        <li class="span2 animate-repeat borderlist description" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search"  ng-mouseenter="mouseEnterItem(item)" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeaveItem(item)">
            <a href="#" class="text-block" >
                <div class="vertical-text " ng-class="{textblur: !item.itemMouseOver && itemMouseOver, textShine : item.itemMouseOver && itemMouseOver}">{{item.name}}</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="bottom" class="horizontal-slide scroller scrollbar-outer" jquery-scrollbar="jQueryBottomScrollbarOptions">
        <li class="span2 animate-repeat  borderlist image-block " ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" ng-mouseenter="mouseEnterItem(item)" ng-mouseleave="mouseLeaveItem(item)">
            <ul class="  ">
                <li class="image-li " ng-repeat="img in item.imgs " >
                    <a href="#" class="">
                        <img src="{{img.img}}" alt=""  ng-class="{imgblur: !item.itemMouseOver && itemMouseOver}" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.containers = {};

$scope.jQueryTopScrollbarOptions = {
    "onScroll": function(y, x){
        if(!$scope.containers.top)
            $scope.containers.top = this.container;
        if($scope.containers.bottom)
            $scope.containers.bottom.scrollLeft(x.scroll);
    }
};

$scope.jQueryBottomScrollbarOptions = {
    "onScroll": function(y, x){
        if(!$scope.containers.bottom)
            $scope.containers.bottom = this.container;
        if($scope.containers.top)
            $scope.containers.top.scrollLeft(x.scroll);
    }
};
```